# MySQL export/import empty/null multilinestring

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, spatial

Using phpMyadmin

I have exported a database which has a table with a spatial multilinestring field. Some of the records in this table have a null entry in this field.

When trying to import, the table fails the import with this message.

## 1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

What do I need to replace the null value with for records where this field is not required?

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked this out so posting back in case anyone else struggles with this.

It was not to do with null entries as I first thought. In phpMyAdmin, the insert scripts batch the inserts together. if you select the option 'include column names in every INSERT statement', each record will have it's own insert statement.

Then when you import, it will show you which record is failing. It was not failing on a null entry.

I then ran a query on the failing record like this to view the points in the multilinestring

```
SELECT ST_ASTEXT(Polylines) FROM myTable WHERE id = 100
```

This showed me that there was only 1 point in one of the Polylines. This was the issue. Importing a polyline with only 1 point into MySQL fails - which makes sense (but it did allow the record to be inserted in the first place). In my case, I set the single point polylines to null to fix this issue.

I was exporting and importing from the same versions of mySQL : 5.7.26